# Powershell and Excel - Start-Process -Wait throws error if excel.exe is already running

Tags: powershell, start-process

Start-Process  -Wait won't work when excel.exe process already exists. When no excel.exe instances are running already the cmdlet works fine. But if there is an instance already running it'll throw an error. I've done some troubleshooting and the problem seems to be that the started process 'nests' itself into the existing one. You'll see that the new excel.exe will start with a separate PID, but after 1-2 seconds this PID disappears and the new instance becomes incapsulated into the existing PID of the excel.exe instance which was running before calling the cmdlet.

Anyone has the proper explanation on this behavior? 
Anyone has a workaround for this? 
All information is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of most Office programs after 2013 (I think). Microsoft decided to stop letting Excel, Word, and PowerPoint (at least) start an additional process by default because of various reasons I will never know.

Your workaround for this is to pass in an argument that tells Excel to open a new instance.

```
Start-Process Excel.exe -ArgumentList "/x" -Wait
```

This should cause you to see multiple intsances of the process now.
[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to open a file just call it this way and you shouldn't get an error:

```
Start-Process excel.exe -wait -ArgumentList "C:\temp\testxlsx.xlsx /x"
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, works indeed if you call excel process without -Wait. Try adding the -Wait parameter, it'll return an error.

Comment: Sorry, let me correct myself. Works indeed if you call excel.exe process, but not when calling a file. Try this, Start-Process c:\temp\test.xlsx -Wait when excel.exe is already running, returns an error.

Comment: Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process 'C:\TEMP\test.xlsx' -ArgumentList "/x" -Wait
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks a lot, your suggestion works like a charm!!